The solution of second order linear ODE $P(x)y^{"}(x)+Q(x)y(x)=0$
Let $P(x)$ be a non-zero continuous function. What is the solution of second order linear ODE $$P(x)y^{"}(x)-y(x)=0?$$
I tried to solve it in the ordinary way but I failed.

It depends very much on what is $P(x)$ in the problem given in the post. Could you show what yout tried (even if it is a dead end) ?

In general this cannot be "solved by quadratures".  If $P$ is a power of $x$, this is a Bessel differential equation.  If $P$ is not too bad, this is a Heun differential equation https://dlmf.nist.gov/31

I supposed that the solution exists (it may not ), then I supposed that the homogenous solution is of the form  $y_{H}=\exp(\lambda x) $ which give $y_{H}=c_{1}\exp(\sqrt(\frac{1}{P(x)})x) +c_{2}\exp(-\sqrt(\frac{1}{P(x)})x)$, however this solution doesn't satisfy the ODE.

@aymanlakehal You should include that attempt in the question statement. The technique it looks like you're using assumes that $\lambda$ is a constant. But when $P$ is constant (and positive) it should give the correct solution.

At any rate, like the other commenters indicate, the approach to a solution really depends on the nature of $P$ (as my previous comment illustrates).

If P and Q are polynomials, there is are families of well-known solutions, https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode-toc2.htm and strategies based on their factorizations https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(86)80010-4 .
Otherwise one divides through $y$ and substitutes $u=y'/y$, $y''/y=u'+u^2$ to get a Riccati differential equation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation
$$
P(x) y''/y + Q(x) =0;
$$
$$
P(x) (u'+u^2) + Q(x) =0;
$$
$$
P(x) u' +P(x) u^2 + Q(x) =0.
$$
The next step is to "guess" a solution $u(x)$ of this first order nonlinear differential equation
and to convert with this guess the equation to a Bernoulli differential equation. This is of course well known, see for example the book "Differentialgleichungen" by Lothar Collatz published by Teubner in 1969.

Thank you for the solution, which is actually straightforward. But in fact the function $P(x)$ is a non polynomial function, the problem in the Riccati equation is that you have to know a particular solution $u_{p}$ in order to solve it, Is there is any known method to find the particular solution of the Riccati equation $$u^{'}+u^{2}=\phi(x)$$

I am only aware of power series "adaptive" solutions proposed in https://www2.mpia-hd.mpg.de/~mathar/public/mathar20070425.pdf .

There are special cases of Ricatti equations which have "known" solutions https://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0123.pdf .
